# Adding column with primary key in existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key

I am trying to add primary key as newly added column `Product_Detail_ID` (`int` and `not null`) in existing table name `Product_Details`. But I am gettin an error.

(There are no other primary or foreign keys assigned to this table.)

```
ALTER TABLE Product_Details
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_Product_Detils_Product_Detail_ID PRIMARY KEY(Product_Detail_ID)
```

> The `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX` statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name `'dbo.Product\_Details'` and the index name `'pk\_Product\_Detils'`. The duplicate key value is (0).

What am I missing?

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Your table has duplicate values in this column, but a primary key requires that the values within the column are unique.  In order to create the PK, you must remove the duplicates.

Comment: Does the table contain data?  In this case you must ensure that the new column has unique values before making it the pk column.

Comment: Have you updated the column with new values?  Or are they all still `0` as shown in your error message.  Make sure that *every* value in that field is different from every other value...

Comment: The message is *sooo* explicit about what is wrong here... Did you read it?

Answer (score 48):

If you want SQL Server to automatically provide values for the new column, make it an identity.

```
ALTER TABLE Product_Details DROP COLUMN Product_Detail_ID
GO
ALTER TABLE Product_Details ADD Product_Detail_ID int identity(1,1) not null
GO
ALTER TABLE Product_Details
add CONSTRAINT pk_Product_Detils_Product_Detail_ID primary key(Product_Detail_ID)
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This query also worked for me but I inserted data manually (edit 200) and then executes with my query..It worked!!

Comment: CAUTION:This will delete all data in this column

Comment: @ShahramBanazadeh i tested this, it doesn't delete.

Comment: @sensei
Drop Column will delete all data in table for this column In your case may Auto identities were equal to manual entered identities –

Answer (score 5):

In mysql, I was able to achieve with following query

`ALTER TABLE table_name ADD new_column int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key`

Comment: For SQL Server use IDENTITY not AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: The question is not tagged for mysql

Answer (score 2):

##### Add Primary Key to *First Position*

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name 
ADD column_name INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST;
```

Reference: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31093217/10204932) | [Tech On The Net](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/tables/alter_table.php)

Comment: The question is not about mysql

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because you have existing data that does not fullfill the constraint.

There are 2 ways to fix it:

- clean up the existing data before adding the constraint
- add the constraint with the "WITH NOCHECK" option, this will stop sql server checking existing data, only new data will be checked

Comment: I would add that using `WITH NOCHECK` is almost always a bad idea :)

Comment: @EricPetroelje I am curious to know why `WITH NOCHECK` is not always a good idea? 

Comment: @DeepamGupta - the point of having a constraint is that the constraint ensures data in the database is valid.  Using `WITH NOCHECK` prevents existing data from being checked, so any applications you write can't actually rely on the constraint being consistent throughout the data

Answer (score -1):

```
ALTER TABLE Jaya 
  ADD CONSTRAINT no primary key(No);
```

here `Jaya` is table name,

`no` is column name,

`ADD CONSTRAINT` is we giving the primary key keyword

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add a new column say deptId to the existing table say department then you can do it using the below code.

```
ALTER TABLE department ADD COLUMN deptID INT;
```

it will create your new column named deptID.

now if you want to add constraint also along with new column while creating it then you can do it using the below code. In the below code I am adding primary key as a constraint. you can add another constraint also instead of primary key like foreign key, default etc.

```
ALTER TABLE department ADD COLUMN deptID INT NOT NULL ADD CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY(deptID);
```

Answer (score -2):

k. friend
command:
sql> alter table tablename add primary key(col_name);

ex: alter table pk_Product_Detils add primary key(Product_Detail_ID);

Comment: What does this answer do different then the already provided answers?