# Cannot add new column to SQL Server table in Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, database, alter-table

I already have a table created with some columns. Now I am trying to add a column with a primary key. I right click the columns, add new column. It lets me add column name, data type as int. Right click on that and setting it to primary key.

When I save this, I get an error

> Unable to modify table.
>   ALTER TABLE only allows columns to be added that can contain nulls, or have a DEFAULT definition specified, or the column being added is an identity or  timestamp column.

Can someone let me know how to alter an already created table? I need to add a primary key to it with auto increment.

Comment: Could you check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13922360/adding-column-with-primary-key-in-existing-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do **4 steps** to get this done:

**Step 1** - create the column

[image]

**Step 2** - make it the primary key

[image]

**Step 3** - bring up the column or table properties

[image]

**Step 4** - define it to be an `IDENTITY` column

[image]

Only *now* - save the changes. And now, it *should* work just fine.